# In a WebApi project should I resolve all dependencies in the WebApi or the business logic layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am currently working on a WebApi that has basic crud operations. Currently the structure is as follows

- `DataAccessRepositories` implements `IDataAccessRepository`
- `BusinessLogicRepositories` implements `IBusinessLogicRepository` and depends on `IDataAccessRepository`
- `WebServicesLayer` (WebApi) depends on `IBusinessLogicRepository`

Currently I am using the Unity resolver to register all my types in the `WebApiConfig` and setting `HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver`.

After discussing with my co workers I am not sure I should be resolving all my dependencoes in `WebServicesLayer` because it means a change to the `DataAccessRepositories` layer would need me to change the `WebServicesLayer`. So I am considering resolving data access repositories in business logic.

What is the approach I should be using and why ?

Comment: What changes to the `DataAccessRepositories` force you to do changes to the `WebServiceLayer`?

Comment: Why is the WebSerivcesLayer also dependent on IDataAccessRepository? Should'nt any logic using it be in BL layer?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo have edited

Comment: Ok, but now the situation is less clear. If WebServicesLayer is not dependent on IDataAccessRepositories, then why do you state that "change to the DataAccessRepositories layer would need me to change the WebServicesLayer" ?

Comment: because I would have to register types in the web services where the dependency are resolved this will make my application less moulder

Comment: I disagree. When applying DI, it is common that the composition root is usually the entry point of your application. In WPF application, it's the app.xaml startup, in console app, its the first lines in Main, and in web serivces, its ServiceHost or something similar. Registering types is different from using the types. Properly utilizing DI makes it easy to swap one implementation with another.

Comment: absolutely use the composition root approach - http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/